# Does extending a class in scala with constructor params add vals (fields) to the class?

Tags: inheritance, scala

Say I have:

```
class A(val foo: String)

class B(foo: String) extends A(foo)
class C(val foo: String) extends A(foo)
class D(override val foo: String) extends A(foo)
class E(bar: String) extends A(bar)
```

I'm interested in how much memory instances of each of these classes take up.  Instances of class A will have a single member variable: foo.

How about classes B,C,D and E? How many member variables will they each have? I suspect E will  have two (E.bar, A.foo), I expect D will have one (A.foo), but I wonder about B and C, might they have two? (B.foo, A.foo)?

Comment: Just a quick note that both var and val create methods on classfiles generated by Scala.   The generation of fields is somewhat opaque to the user, so you cannot rely on any particular field being generated or the name of such a field.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of the examples that compile (`A`, `B`, `D`, `E`) take exactly the same amount of storage space.  In fact, even

```
class F(val bar: String) extends A(bar)
```

will have the data stored in one field--it just gets an extra accessor method for the same field.  However, if you

```
class G(var bar: String) extends A(bar)
```

then a new field is constructed.

You can check all this by compiling your examples above and looking at the bytecode from `javap -c Classname` (note the putfield at `2:` in the constructor of `A`):

```
public class Sizes$A extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
public java.lang.String foo();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield    #11; //Field foo:Ljava/lang/String;
   4:   areturn

public Sizes$A(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   putfield    #11; //Field foo:Ljava/lang/String;
   5:   aload_0
   6:   invokespecial   #18; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   9:   return    
}
```

(And the lack of an extra putfield in `F`...)

```
public Sizes$F(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   invokespecial   #15; //Method Sizes$A."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   5:   return
```

(And the presence of one again in `G`...)

```
public Sizes$G(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   putfield    #11; //Field bar:Ljava/lang/String;
   5:   aload_0
   6:   aload_1
   7:   invokespecial   #18; //Method Sizes$A."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   10:  return
```

Answer (score 7):

You class `C` will require an `override` keyword on `val foo` to compile, rendering it identical to `D`. It will store its own copy of foo. You class `B` does not add storage *unless* someplace outside its constructor body there is a reference to `foo`. That would force a hidden field to be created to hold the constructor parameter. The constructor body is all the code within the class definition *and outside any method body*.

Addendum:

```
package storage

    class A(val foo: String)

    class B(             foo: String) extends A(foo)
//  class C(         val foo: String) extends A(foo)
    class D(override val foo: String) extends A(foo)
    class E(             bar: String) extends A(bar)
    class F(             bar: String) extends A(bar) { def barbar: String = bar }
```

I am perplexed by this:

```
% javap -private storage.F
Compiled from "Storage.scala"
public class storage.F extends storage.A implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public java.lang.String barbar();
    public storage.F(java.lang.String);
}
```

What is method `barbar` using to get its return value?

Comment: `B` would also not add a field for `foo` in case you accessed it outside of the constructor body but use the parent's accessor.

Comment: Thanks for the info Randall. Just to clarify: are you saying that instances of D will have two copies of foo?

Comment: @Alex Black: Yes. The `javap` command is good for disclosing these details, but be aware that you need to use its `-private` option to see all the private fields that back the accessor (and mutator) methods that the compiler uses to mediate access to those fields.